# “Unable to resolve the following parameters:” jags error for Latent Class Model

Tags: r, bayesian, jags

I'm looking to fit a Bayesian latent class model in JAGS, but am running into an issue, which I'm seeking help to resolve.

The model I'm trying to fit is described below (model details can be found at https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v061i13/v61i13.pdf). (I understand that I could just use this package, however, I'm trying to manually code this in JAGS as I'm about to add extra model complexities which are not compatible with BayesLCA.)

My JAGS attempt for this model is given below. $n$, $ng$, $nm$ denote the number of observations, the number of latent groups, and the number of survey responses (respectively). It appears as though I have a directed cycle within this code (x->pi_norm->group->x), but I can't work out how to avoid this.

Data and R script:

```
x = matrix(0, nrow = 40, ncol = 4)
x[1:10,1] <- 1
x[11:20,2] <- 1
x[21:30,3] <- 1
x[31:40,4] <- 1
ng = 4
nm = dim(x)[2]
n  = dim(x)[1]

jags.data = list("x" = x, "n" = n, "ng" = ng, "nm" = nm)
jags <- jags.model("model1.bug", 
               data     = jags.data,
               n.chains = 1,                                
               n.adapt  = 1000)
samples <- coda.samples(model          = jags, 
               variable.names = c("pi_norm", "theta"), 
               n.iter         = 2000, 
               thin           = 1)
```

Jags model:

```
model{ 
# prior specification
tau[1:ng] ~ ddirch(rep(1,ng))
for (g in 1:ng) {
    for (m in 1:nm) {
      theta[g, m] ~ dunif(0,1)  
    }
  }
#likelihood specification
for (i in 1:n) {
  for (g in 1:ng){
    p[i, g, 1:nm] <- (theta[g, 1:nm]^x[i, 1:nm])*(1-theta[g, 1:nm])^(1-x[i, 1:nm])  # p(X_im|theta_gm)
    pi[i, g] <- prod(p[i, g, ]*tau[])   # p(X_i|theta_g)
    pi_norm[i, g] <- pi[i, g]/sum(pi[i, ])  # normalise
  }

  group[i] ~ dcat(pi_norm[i, 1:ng])  # equivalent to multinomial
  for (m in 1:nm) {
     x[i, m] ~ dbern(theta[group[i], m])  
  }
 }
}
```

The error that I obtain is as follows.

```
Error in jags.model("model1.bug", data = jags.data, n.chains = 1, n.adapt = 1000) : 
RUNTIME ERROR:
Unable to resolve the following parameters:
pi[1,1:4] (line 20)
pi[2,1:4] (line 20)
...
pi[40,1:4] (line 20)
pi_norm[1,1:4] (line 23)
pi_norm[2,1:4] (line 23)
pi_norm[3,1:4] (line 23)
pi_norm[4,1:4] (line 23)
```

Any help would be really appreciated.